# Need someone to explain the structure of the sentence for me

Tags: grammar

For the following sentences:

> It is invalid, however, to apply both attributes to the same settings property.
>   Such an attempt will cause an exception to be thrown.

First, are the above sentences grammatically correct?

Second, what is "to apply both attributes to the same settings property" here
(e.g. is "to apply both attributes to the same settings property" a subject, or something else in the sentence)?

Third, how can we use "to apply both attributes to the same settings property" after "however" in the above sentences?

Comment: What do **you** think and why do **you** think so? We wouldn't want to deprive you of the experience of thinking about it, after all.

Comment: How we can use it after _however_ in the above sentence? Why, exactly the way it _is_ used in the sentence, of course!

Answer (score 0):

It is grammatically correct... depending on the person you ask. 
My English professor would have us change it to something like: 
"It is invalid, however, to apply both attributes to the same settings property, for such an attempt will cause an exception to be thrown." Or even... 
"It is invalid, however, to apply both attributes to the same settings property;such an attempt will cause an exception to be thrown.